# Is 'She has been taken' active or passive voice?

Tags: passive-voice, perfect-constructions

> She has been taken

I want to know - Is it passive voice or active voice?

If it is passive, then what is object, subject, verb in this sentence?  If it's not a passive voice, then we use 2 two past participle in this sentence.

Answer (score 8):

This construction is *present perfect passive*.

When you talk about 'subjects' and 'objects' you must be careful that you do not confuse **syntactic roles**, the functions word or phrases play in a particular sentence, with **semantic roles**, the functions words or phrases play with respect to the meanings of verbs.

The core **syntactic roles** are subject, verb, and object. Every full sentence has a subject and and a verb; there will only be an object if the meaning of the verb and the form of the sentence require it.

A transitive verb like *take*, for instance, typically involves two **semantic roles**:

- the Agent, the person who performs the act of taking, and
- the Patient, the entity which the Agent takes

In an active sentence, the Agent is cast in the syntactic role of subject, the verb is cast in an active construction, and the Patient is cast in the syntactic role of object:

> <sub>subject</sub>**The kidnappers**<sup>AGENT</sup>   <sub>activeverb</sub>**took**   <sub>object</sub>**the little girl**<sup>PATIENT</sup>

In a passive sentence, however, the Patient becomes the subject and the verb is recast in the passive construction. The Agent may be omitted; if present, it is cast in the form of a preposition phrase headed by *by*:

> <sub>subject</sub>**The little girl**<sup>PATIENT</sup>   <sub>passive verb</sub>**was taken**   <sub>preposition phrase</sub>*by the kidnappers*<sup>AGENT</sup>

In your sentence

- The passive subject (the 'Patient' who undergoes the action) is *she*.
- The finite verb is the *perfect* auxiliary *HAVE*; it is cast in the present-tense form *has* and requires its complement to be cast in the past-participle form:

  > She has *past participle* ...
- The next verb is the *passive* auxiliary *BE*; it is cast in the past-participle form *been* as the complement of the perfect auxiliary and requires its complement to be cast in the past-participle form:

  > She has been *past participle* ...
- The final verb is the lexical verb *TAKE*; it is cast in the past-participle form *taken* as the complement of the passive auxiliary:

  > She has been taken.

The 'Agent' who performs the action is not expressed in your sentence.

Comment: i can't understand what you sad in this post and you didn't clear that how "
she has been" is past participle and in passive voice we usually take object at the beginning of the sentence then how "she" is used here as a subject here

Comment: @rajivDixit This answer is very clear. In the _passive_, the subject is the person or thing which is acted upon. Ask yourself: "Who or what has been taken?" The answer is **She**. Therefore **she** is the subject. I know you are having a difficult time understanding the verb "to be" and the use of the past participle "been," because you have asked so many questions about it. The passive voice _always_ uses a form of "to be." I hope you will spend more time reading your textbook.  Read and _understand_ this [link](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-voice-passive.htm)

Comment: @rajivDixit At the top I have added an explanation of the difference between semantic and syntactic roles, which I think you are confusing.

Comment: @StoneyB - In stackex markdown, does &nbsp; force a space _only_ within a blockquote?

Comment: Sounds as if Mr Dixit, in searching the web for answers, has come across a discussion of the passive from a _functional grammar_ perspective; thus the confusion of terms between subject/object.

Comment: @P.E.Dant `&nbsp;` works anywhere in a Q or A, but not in comments.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Does FG analyze a passive as *obj BE Verben by subj*?!

Comment: @StoneyB So it seems in light of [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/85068). Mr Kay takes much longer to say the same thing [here](http://web.stanford.edu/class/linguist289/kay79.pdf).